# A batch program to rename a single file only

Tags: batch-file

I have the following in a batch file. When executed it renames all files in the directory with the current date prefixed on the file name.

How can I modify this to only change a single selected file? The user will select the open with selection and execute the batch to rename the file. The name of the file will always be different, so I need it to be a variable.

```
for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2% %%a"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set /p "$file=Enter the name of the file to rename :"
rename "%$File%" "%date:~-4%%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2% %$File%"
```